# How to use sequelizejs in the browser?

Tags: client-side, sequelize.js

Is it possible to use sequelize on the client side? Are there solutions for that?

Knex.js runs quite fine with the websql provider, is there a way to use sequelize the same way or with another adapter?

Comment: Do you mean us Sequelize against a SQL-lite DB in the browser? I'm curious about Sequelize on the client side, but for data validation.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize can be used in a web browser. See `sequelize-browser` package: https://npmjs.com/package/sequelize-browser